# I want to create a step by step order and this is what I have so far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm fresh from the oven when it comes to JavaScript. I've been an active anonymous reader and learner *(or lurker)* for a few months and I already feel quite comfortable coding HTML and CSS, but JavaScript is the new person I'm trying to get to know.

To explain my personal task, I am trying to create a **step by step** order. The functionality I'm trying to accomplish is when you press on a specific div *(one of the **Services** in my JSFiddle)* you'll get to step 2, and when you select another div in step 2 *(the **Packages** in my JSFiddle)* you'll get to step 3, and so on. However, the issue here is that if I've already chosen *Service 1* and want to choose *Service 2*  instead, the toggle function backfires. I'm. A. Noob.

What I am trying to do is a kind of show/hide, where if one of the divs has the class **selected** it will display the proper hidden content for that div. If it's not selected it will stay hidden. I've been using *dataid="#"* to tell which div to target what the next step is.

So, do you have any suggestions or tips for what I can do to accomplish my quest?

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/superladremi/L3c1e2xn/).

```
<!-- START SERVICE 1 -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="service noselect" dataid="service_1">
      <h4>Service 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- END SERVICE 1 -->
```

The JS:

```
// to show the unique div hidden behind each different service, dataid="#div"
$('.service').bind('click', function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('dataid');
    $("#"+target).toggle('fast');
});

// for toggling the ".selected" on click of service(s)
$('.service').click(function(event) {
$('.service').not(this).removeClass('selected');
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Thanks alot <3

Comment: Is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/L3c1e2xn/1/

Comment: @MichaelCoker ..... that was faster than what I expected. It is very close for what I'm going for, but if I were going to have a step 3, what can I do to make step 2 clickable and also selected? Any suggestions there? I only made 2 steps in my JSFiddle, but 3 unique hidden content for each service. If I wanted one more or even two more steps, how would that look according to your code? Thanks alot by the way.

Comment: @MichaelCoker or I might just play around with the classes and change your code upon class changes, I dont know if that's a hard way but it might conclude to a solution, perhaps. Have'nt tried yet.

Comment: Just posted an answer with general, re-usable logic based on your current code that could build steps indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simplified version of the logic I think you're trying to achieve.

```js
$('a').on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // remove selected class from links after the current one
  $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('a').removeClass('selected');
  // remove selected from siblings, toggle current selected class
  $(this).siblings('a').removeClass('selected').end().toggleClass('selected');
  var $target = $('#'+$(this).attr('data-id'));
  if ($target.length) {
    // hide any steps after the current one that may be shown
    $(this).closest('section').nextAll('section').find('.step').not($target).removeClass('active');
    // toggle display of selected step
    $target.toggleClass('active'); 
  } else {
    console.log('do something else to end this thing');
  }
})
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  display: block;
}
a {
  transition: color .25s;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.selected {
  color: red;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <a href="#" data-id="one">1</a> 
  <a href="#" data-id="two">2</a>
  <a href="#" data-id="three">3</a>
</section>

<section>
  <div id="one" class="step">
    <h1>1</h1>
    <a href="#" data-id="one-one">1</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="one-two">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="one-three">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="step">
    <h1>2</h1>
    <a href="#" data-id="two-one">1</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="two-two">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="two-three">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="step">
    <h1>3</h1>
    <a href="#" data-id="three-one">1</a> 
    <a href="#" data-id="three-two">2</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="three-three">3</a>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div id="one-one" class="step">
    <h1>1-1</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="one-two" class="step">
    <h1>1-2</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="one-three" class="step">
    <h1>1-3</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="two-one" class="step">
    <h1>2-1</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="two-two" class="step">
    <h1>2-2</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="two-three" class="step">
    <h1>2-3</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="three-one" class="step">
    <h1>3-1</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="three-two" class="step">
    <h1>3-2</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
  <div id="three-three" class="step">
    <h1>3-3</h1>
    <a href="#">1</a> 
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You are a true God. A hero in my eyes, I've been looking for something like this, but with this infinite solution... Just perfection. Appreciated so much. Thanks, many thanks!!!

Comment: @superladremi hah! no problem :)

Comment: Sorry for poking you with my madness, again. Would it be possible to make one specific section to have multi selection if we give the section a class name?

Comment: @superladremi anything's possible ;) But FYI, I know you're new to SO - it's bad etiquette to go outside asking a single, clear question per post, and having a conversation and/or working through additional stuff in the comments. If you have a new problem, you should make a new post.

Comment: Ah, right, of course. Thank you for giving me the heads up of how things roll here.